IntelliJ spring-boot-devtools behavior
I'm switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ CE 2024.3.1.1 and I opened a Spring Boot 3.4.1 project create with Spring Initliazr.
As I said, I'm using Spring Boot 3.4.1, Java 21, Maven 3.9.9 (Bundled) and no others, there isn't a line of code. I have just some import:

spring-boot-starter-data (H2 database),
spring-boot-starter-web,
h2database,
spring-boot-devtools,
lombok (1.18.12)

I notice that, even if the spring-boot-devtools is on the pom and the Spring Assistant plugin installed, when I change something, the app doesn't reload.
Is there a way to fix that?

What do you expect and what it happened? Remember you are using community edition.

In addition to installing spring-boot-devtools, you also need to enable automatic build in IntelliJ.

Open Settings
Select Build, Execution, Deployment
On the Compiler page, select Build project automatically.


Thanks a lot man.
